# No Module Named "requests" even though I installed it already in pycharm

Tags: module, python-requests, command-prompt, interpreter, named

This is the error i get from command prompt:
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\12103\PycharmProjects\pythonProject1\googlesearch.py", line 9, in 
import requests
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'requests'

i read somewhere saying it might be the environment or something? help would be great thanks

Comment: Yes it's most likely the environment. See what environment is set in PyCharm: **Run > Edit Configurations** menu, and then look in the **Python interpreter** box. Make sure you use the same when you run in the command prompt. You may need to activate that environment in the command prompt first.

Comment: @tromgy hmm it's the same .. so im not sure how to fix, when i get to the py file, it says file directory is invalid

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.